# iPhone vibrate on button press

Tags: iphone, titanium, vibration

I am creating an iPhone app in which I want the iPhone to vibrate once I press a button. I tried using `Ti.Media.vibrate([0,500])` but it did not work.

Here is the code I used.

```
 btn1.addEventListener('singletap',function(e){
   Ti.Media.vibrate([0,500]);
 });

 btn2.addEventListener('singletap',function(e){
   Ti.Media.vibrate([0,500]);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Supplying a pattern will not work on iOS:

> On Android, Mobile Web and Tizen, a pattern argument can be provided to specify a vibration pattern.

Just try without the pattern argument:

```
btn1.addEventListener('click',function(e){
   Ti.Media.vibrate();
});
```